# CSS grid with auto-fill: a card does not grow when it can

Tags: css, flexbox, grid, autofill

Several cards with min/max width have to be placed in a single row.
They have to fill it if possible.

I tried using 2 rules:

```css
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(50px, 1fr))
```

and

```css
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(50px, 1fr))
```

Everything works fine if there are many cards. The issue is when they are too few to fill in the row.

With `auto-fill` the card does not grow to its maximum width when there's enough space. There's a strange jumping.

With `auto-fit` it grows, but then it grows further, or - if the card max width is set - the gap starts growing.

```css
.container {
  padding: 24px 8px 8px 8px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: grid;
  gap: 8px;
  height: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.fill {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(50px, 1fr));
}

.fit {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(50px, 1fr));
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.flex > div {
  flex: 1 1 100px;
}

.container > div {
  height: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.card-restrict > div {
  min-width: 50px;
  max-width: 100px;  
}

.container > span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 8px;
  height: 24px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container fit">
  <span>auto-fit: card grows more than 100px</span>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
<div class="container fill">
  <span>auto-fill: card does not grow to 100px when it can</span>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
<div class="container fit card-restrict">
  <span>auto-fit + min/max width: gap between cards grows indefinitely</span>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
<div class="container fill card-restrict">
  <span>auto-fill + min/max width: card does not grow to 100px when it can</span>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
<div class="container flex card-restrict">
  <span>flex + min/max width: it does not work when overflow</span>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
```

There's also a `flex` version. This is how it's expected to work if cards don't overflow. Is it possible to achieve this flex-ish behavior in CSS grid?

Comment: In your flex approach, change `flex:1 1 100px` to `flex:1` can constraint width between 50px and 100px when overflow. Is that what you need? Or is it required to use grid?

Comment: the question is why not using the flexbox approach that is doing what you want?

Comment: @TemaniAfif - flex gives the correct result if cards don't overflow. If they overflow, then flex cards just go out of the container. In the last case grid auto-fit or auto-fill gives the correct behavior. One way is to use JS to detect if cards overflow or not, and apply grid either flex. But it might be achievable using CSS and grid only.

Comment: I ended up using JS. Resize Observer checks if there's overflow or not and applies flex or grid.